# How can i convert image sequence to video in matlab

Tags: matlab

when i used im2frame for converting image sequence to video,
I am getting this message :

??? Error using ==> im2frame
 Indexed movie frame must have a non-empty colormap

Error in ==> program at 141
     frm = im2frame(im,map);

if someone can explain what I should do, I will be grateful.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The video will be encoded in full color, so if your frames are only 2-dimensional (i.e, you have a grayscale image instead of red/green/blue), then you need to specify a colormap for converting the image.  You should be able to use the command

```
im2frame(frame, gray)
```

where `gray` is the colormap, just as with `surf`, `imshow`, and other plotting commands.  Other colormap choices are `hot`, `cool`, `pink`, `bone`, `copper`, and `flag`.

Comment: **Error using im2frame
Indexed movie data values must be legal colormap indices:
""1.0 <= value <= length(colormap) for double-precision movie data, and
""0 <= value <= length(colormap)-1 for uint8 movie data** Can you tell what this means ?? Thanks